# Error while importing Libp2p package in blockchain

Tags: blockchain, nodejs, ipfs, angularjs, libp2p

I have installed some js-libp2p's packages on my Ethereum Blockchain-ipfs project and I wrote some codes like below.

```
const TCP = require('libp2p-tcp');
const MulticastDNS = require('libp2p-mdns');
const WS = require('libp2p-websockets');
const KadDHT = require('libp2p-kad-dht')
const mplex = require('libp2p-mplex');
const secio = require('libp2p-secio');
const libp2p = require('libp2p');
```

But the multicast-dns ,libp2p and libp2p-kad-dht module is showing some error.

> ERROR in ./~/libp2p/src/index.js
>
> Module parse failed: /home/toshiba/Documents/sul/ipfs/CannesNew Full Codejan17/SportsFull CodeTESTRpc12may/SportsFull Code1april/node_modules/libp2p/src/index.js Unexpected token (120:8)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>
> |       this._dht = new DHT(this._switch, {
>   |         datastore: this.datastore,
>   |         ...this._config.dht
>   |       })
>   |     }
>
> @ ./app/backend/app.js 62:15-32
>
> @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/backend/app.js

**Environment**

Npm version: 6.4.1

Node version: 8.12.0

Os:Ubuntu 18.04

Anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

I already imported this js-libp2p packages in my meanstack application with normal node and npm and it works well.But when I am importing this packages in blockchain application, it is showing the above error.

My current webpack version is 2.2.1

My **webpack.config.js** code is shown below,

```
...
module: {
rules: [
{
test: /\.css$/,
use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
}
],
loaders: [
{ test: /\.json$/, use: 'json-loader' },
{
test: /\.js$/,
exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
loader: 'babel-loader',
query: {
presets: ['es2015'],
plugins: ['transform-runtime']
}
}
]
},
...
```

Comment: The package.json says it requires node >= 6.0 but their .travis.yml file says node_js = 10. I'd guess you need at least node 10, but probably it is better if you create an issue in their github repo so they can document it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
exclude: {
  test: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  not: [
    // Do not exclude this dependency
    /libp2p/
  ]
}
```